# Visual studio text editor: how change the color of Log statements?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010 and I have a lot of log (log4net) statements in my code.

```
if(Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    Logger.DebugFormat("varX = {0}", varX);
}
```

I don't want to add #regions because the number of such logging block is very large. 
Is there any way to change the color of these lines to 'Gray' to distinguish them from normal code?

Best regards,
Zach